# How to get values between date from group by join in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i tried to get values between date but it doesn't work. if i provide dates in where clause it get values `totalhrs` as '00:00'.

```
select B.emp_reader_id
      ,B.emp_name as Name
      ,Ds.desn_name as Desn_Name
      ,A.TotalHRsS
      ,a.min_date
      ,a.max_date
from employee B
    inner join(select s.emp_reader_id
                     ,max(att_date) as max_date
                     ,min(att_date) as min_date
                     ,TotalHRsS = right('0' + convert(varchar(9),DATEDIFF(ms,'00:00:00.000', TotalHrs)) / 3600 )),2)
                                  + ':' 
                                  + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),SUM(DATEDIFF(ms,'00:00:00.000', TotalHrs)) / 60) % 60 ),2)
                                  + ':'
                                  + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(ms,'00:00:00.000', TotalHrs)) % 60 )),2) 
               from Daily_attendance_data s
                   left outer join employee bb
                       on s.emp_reader_id = bb.emp_reader_id
               group by s.emp_reader_id
              ) A
        on B.emp_reader_id = A.emp_reader_id 
    left outer join departments D
        on B.dept_id = D.dept_id 
    left outer join designation Ds
        on B.desn_id = DS.DESN_ID
where (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),A.min_date, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2019-01-01', 23)
    and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),A.max_date, 23) <=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2019-01-30', 23))
```

Output:

```
1024    RAVEENDRAN K    NULL    89:26:40    2019-01-01  2019-01-30  
2       Haneef          NULL    00:00:00    2019-01-01  2019-01-30      
1043    KABIL R         NULL    00:00:00    2019-01-01  2019-01-30      
1005    D KRISHNADAS    NULL    21:56:40    2019-01-01  2019-01-30  
1041    SATISH GUMMADI  NULL    60:33:20    2019-01-01  2019-01-30
```

above is my expected output. i need `totalhrs` between dates

Comment: Your expected output is not reasonable, max number of hours are 48 for two days. Do I understand you correctly that the issue is with the sub-query in the inner join? If so why not make the question about only that query and add some sample data and expected output for that query only?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson edited.

Comment: Sure, but you have done nothing to simplify or clarify the question